# Shell - what does <<-'EOF' mean

Tags: bash, shell

I have used `< file.txt` to set a file as the standard input.

But I encountered a new one, `<<-'EOF'`， in this following command.

```
$ sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo <<-'EOF'
[dockerrepo]
name=Docker Repository
baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg
EOF
```

How should I understand `<<-'word'`

`<<` means what? (I know `>> file1.txt` means appending to the file, file1.txt)

does `-'word'` means setting `word` as the ending symbol?

Any links to references/documentations are appreciated~

Comment: this is called here document: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: If you open `man bash` and search on `<<` or `<<-`, you will find a detailed explanation.